# Regular expressions in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

In cells of column `e_vis_name` I have organization structure where divisions divided with `\` symbol, e.g.

- Moscow\Direction
- Yaroslavl\Sales
- Omsk\Commercial center\Sales

I need to cut everything after first \ symbol to get the following result:

- Moscow
- Yaroslavl
- Omsk

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a combination of [LEFT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) and [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) like this:

```
SELECT LEFT(colname, CHARINDEX('\', colname)-1) FROM table
```

**EDIT:** In the case where you don't have a `\` symbol, if you just want to grab the whole column instead you can do this:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('\', colname) > 0 THEN LEFT(colname, CHARINDEX('\', colname)-1)
    ELSE ISNULL(colname, '') 
    END
FROM table
```

This says, "If there is a `\`, then take the characters up to that point, otherwise take the whole column. And if the column is `NULL` then just set an empty string."

I'm sure you can adapt this to your purposes.

Comment: Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: There are some divisions which don't have '\' symbol, e.g. 'JSC '

Comment: That error was due to \ being missing in that column. I have added a check which returns the whole column in the absence of \.

Answer (score 1):

there are many options how you can achieve what you need, below several examples of them

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- TEMP TABLE WITH DATA SAMPLE
DECLARE @table AS TABLE ( Division VARCHAR(100) )

INSERT INTO @table ( Division                       )
VALUES             ( 'Moscow\Direction'             )
,                  ( 'Yaroslavl\Sales'              )
,                  ( 'Omsk\Commercial center\Sales' )
,                  ( 'Voronezh'                     )

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- variant using PARSENAME
SELECT REVERSE(PARSENAME(REVERSE(REPLACE(Division, '\', '.')), 1)) AS Town
FROM @table AS T

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- variant using SUBSTRING AND CHARINDEX
SELECT  SUBSTRING(division, 1,
                  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('\', division) = 0 THEN LEN(Division)
                       ELSE CHARINDEX('\', division) - 1
                  END) AS Town
FROM    @table AS T

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- variant using SUBSTRING AND PATINDEX
SELECT  SUBSTRING(division, 1,
                  CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%\%', division) = 0 THEN LEN(Division)
                       ELSE PATINDEX('%\%', division) - 1
                  END) AS Town
FROM    @table AS T

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- variant using LEFT AND PATINDEX

SELECT  LEFT(division,
             CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%\%', division) = 0 THEN LEN(Division)
                  ELSE PATINDEX('%\%', division) - 1
             END) AS Town
FROM    @table AS T

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- variant using LEFT AND CHARINDEX
SELECT  LEFT(division,
             CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('\', division) = 0 THEN LEN(Division)
                  ELSE CHARINDEX('\', division) - 1
             END) AS Town
FROM    @table AS T

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- variant using recursive cte, substring, top with ties by Row_number()
;
WITH tally
AS (SELECT n = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n = n + 1
    FROM tally
    WHERE n < 100)

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES SUBSTRING(A.Division,1,B.n-1) AS Town
FROM @table AS A
JOIN tally  AS B ON SUBSTRING(A.Division + '\', B.n , 1)= '\'
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.Division ORDER BY B.n)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- variant using recursive cte, substring, row_number, subquery
;
WITH tally
AS (SELECT n = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n = n + 1
    FROM tally
    WHERE n < 100)

SELECT T.TOWN
FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING(A.Division,1,B.n-1) AS TOWN,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.Division ORDER BY B.n) AS RN
      FROM @table AS A JOIN tally  AS B ON SUBSTRING(A.Division + '\', B.n , 1)= '\'
      ) AS T
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: This varriant suits me, thanks a lot 4 your help.                                       -- variant using SUBSTRING AND CHARINDEX
SELECT  SUBSTRING(division, 1,
                  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('\', division) = 0 THEN LEN(Division)
                       ELSE CHARINDEX('\', division) - 1
                  END) AS Town
FROM    @table AS T

Comment: I accepted the first correct answer- it seems to me the most fair way. But as for me I like REPLACE(LEFT(e_vis_name, CHARINDEX('\', e_vis_name + '\', 1)), '\', '') most of all although other are correct also.

Answer (score 1):

As some alternatives:

**Using `LEFT` :**

```
REPLACE(LEFT(e_vis_name, CHARINDEX('\', e_vis_name + '\', 1)), '\', '')
```

---

**Using `SUBSTRING` :**

```
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(e_vis_name, 1, CHARINDEX('\', e_vis_name + '\', 1)), '\', '')
```

---

**Using `STUFF` :**

```
STUFF(e_vis_name + '\', CHARINDEX('\', e_vis_name + '\', 1), 512, '')
```

---

**Using `PARSENAME` :**

```
REVERSE(PARSENAME(REVERSE(REPLACE(e_vis_name, '\','.')), 1))

-- or REPLACE(REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(REPLACE(e_vis_name, '.', CHAR(8))), '\','.'), 1)), CHAR(8), '.')
```

or

```
PARSENAME(REPLACE(e_vis_name, '\','.'), LEN(e_vis_name) - LEN(REPLACE(e_vis_name, '\', '')) + 1)
-- or REPLACE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(e_vis_name, '.', CHAR(8)), '\','.'), LEN(e_vis_name) - LEN(REPLACE(e_vis_name, '\', '')) + 1) , CHAR(8), '.')
```

Comment: REPLACE(LEFT(e_vis_name, CHARINDEX('\', e_vis_name + '\', 1)), '\', '') quete simple and elegent - and also works, ty

Comment: @Cove I test all of the above functions, all them should work in all cases ;).

Comment: shA.t, I appreciate you sharing of knowledge and believe that all of your  examples are ok, but I didn't have enough  time to test all of the functions in this topic. I had a task which is now complete and my main target is to learn SQL. So every evening I return here and test new variants trying to understand how it all works. And once again I want to thank all for the help.